# Joining 2 tables with user input

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Alright I have the foreign keys set up and I'm able to join the tables via the `sql` tab in phpmyadmin, but I can't figure out how to get things to work properly when I allow a user to input the values via a form. Right now I'm just playing around with a very basic form that allows first name, last name, and phone number. First and Last name get sent to a table named `Customer` and phone number gets passed to a table called `Customer_Number`. The problem is that now when I enter values into the input fields, First and Last name saved to the DB table, but phone number doesn't save and spits out this error message ``` Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (``.Customer_Number, CONSTRAINT Customer_Number_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer (Customer_ID)) ```

Is there a way I can just add these values and the foreign key for my `Customer_Number` table update according to the correct customer?

Here is my code:

```
 <?php

        $con=mysqli_connect("");
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                echo "There was a mistake connecting". mysqli_connect_errno();
                }
        $First=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["FirstName"]);
        $Last=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["LastName"]);
            if(!empty($_POST["FirstName"]) && !empty($_POST["LastName"])){
                $sql="INSERT INTO Customer(First,Last)
                    VALUE('$First', '$Last')";

                        if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
                            die("ERROR". mysqli_error($con));
                            }else{
                                echo"record added";
                                }
                            }
                                    mysql_close($con);
                            ?>
     <?php

        $con=mysqli_connect("");
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                echo "There was a mistake connecting". mysqli_connect_errno();
                }
        $Phone=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Number"]);

            if(!empty($_POST["Number"])){
                $sql="INSERT INTO Customer_Number(Number)
                    VALUE('$Phone')";

                        if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
                            die("ERROR". mysqli_error($con));
                            }else{
                                echo"record added";
                                }
                            }
                                    mysql_close($con);
                            ?>
```

And here is my table information:

```
CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
`Customer_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`First` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Last` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Customer_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `Customer_Number` (
`Num_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Customer_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Num_ID`),
KEY `Customer_ID` (`Customer_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `Customer_Number_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Customer_ID`) REFERENCES `Customer`         (`Customer_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I know there has got to be a way to do this, but I'm new to this and my google searches has only really covered how to do this via phpMyAdmin and manually entering in the foreign key values.

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions.

Comment: is that the issue or are you just informing me that I need to clean things up to meet programming standards?

Comment: That is not the entire issue, but you need clean, working code before we can attack that.

Comment: In no way am I trying to be argumentative, but the code did work originally, it was only after I added the foreign key to `customer_number` that I started getting that error. I just wanted to add that to make sure we were on the same page and not talking about two different issues.

Comment: The code might have worked originally, because you call `mysql_close`. This call will fail, because of the incompatibility between `mysql` and `mysqli`. That might issue a warning, which is often disabled (but may be logged). Apart from that, the function returns false and the resource is just kept open until the end of the script. No big issue, but is an error nonetheless, and any other mixups would cause actual failure during execution. So it's not just about standards, it is a real concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Customer_Number.Customer_ID` is a foreign key pointing to the corresponding `Customer`  row, you need to set `Customer_Number.Customer_ID` to the correct value when inserting the number after inserting the `Customer`.

As long as you're using the same connection (ie skip closing/reopening it between the queries), you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the Customer_ID of the just inserted customer, something like (the SQL part only);

```
INSERT INTO Customer(First,Last) 
  VALUES ('$First', '$Last')

INSERT INTO Customer_Number(Customer_ID, Number) 
  VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$Phone')
```